# realm react-native closed instance

Tags: react-native, realm

I use realm in a react-native app, and I am often facing an error telling me that the realm is closed.

Here is my setup :

```ts
// schema.ts
import 'react-native-get-random-values';
import { Realm } from '@realm/react';
import { Account } from './Account';
import { Article } from './Article';

export const realmSchema = [
    Account.schema,
    Article.schema
]

export const realmConfig: Realm.Configuration = {
    schema: realmSchema
}
```

```ts
// RealmContext.ts
import { createRealmContext } from "@realm/react";
import { realmConfig } from "./schema";

export const realmContext = createRealmContext(realmConfig);
```

Because I also use realm outside of components, I had an error telling me that I couldn't use realm hooks / context outside of components, so I made a 2nd "classical" realm instance without createRealmContext :

```ts
// RealmInstance.ts

import { Realm } from '@realm/react';
import { realmConfig } from "./schema";

class RealmInstance {
    private static _instance: RealmInstance;
    public realm!: Realm;
    private constructor() {}

    public static getInstance(): RealmInstance {
        if (!RealmInstance._instance) {
            RealmInstance._instance = new RealmInstance();
            RealmInstance._instance.realm = new Realm(realmConfig);
        }

        return RealmInstance._instance;
    }
}

export default RealmInstance.getInstance().realm;
```

First I tried with new Realm(realmConfig), but I had the "closed realm issue" all the time, so now I use a singleton, but I keep getting the message sometimes.

Is it a GC issue ? what should I do to keep the instance opened ?

Edit :

Here is the stack of the error :

Basically, when I make the `RealmInstance.objects<Article>(Article.schema.name)` call.

```
This error is located at:
    in MoreStackNavigator (created by SceneView)
    in StaticContainer
    in EnsureSingleNavigator (created by SceneView)
    in SceneView (created by BottomTabView)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by Screen)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by Background)
    in Background (created by Screen)
    in Screen (created by BottomTabView)
    in RNSScreen
    in Unknown (created by InnerScreen)
    in Suspender (created by Freeze)
    in Suspense (created by Freeze)
    in Freeze (created by DelayedFreeze)
    in DelayedFreeze (created by InnerScreen)
    in InnerScreen (created by Screen)
    in Screen (created by MaybeScreen)
    in MaybeScreen (created by BottomTabView)
    in RNSScreenNavigationContainer (created by ScreenContainer)
    in ScreenContainer (created by MaybeScreenContainer)
    in MaybeScreenContainer (created by BottomTabView)
    in RNCSafeAreaProvider (created by SafeAreaProvider)
    in SafeAreaProvider (created by SafeAreaInsetsContext)
    in SafeAreaProviderCompat (created by BottomTabView)
    in BottomTabView (created by BottomTabNavigator)
    in PreventRemoveProvider (created by NavigationContent)
    in NavigationContent
    in Unknown (created by BottomTabNavigator)
    in BottomTabNavigator (created by BottomTabNavigator)
    in BottomTabNavigator (created by App)
    in EnsureSingleNavigator
    in BaseNavigationContainer
    in ThemeProvider
    in NavigationContainerInner (created by App)
    in RCTSafeAreaView (created by App)
    in Unknown (created by App)
    in App
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in AppContainer
    in MyApp(RootComponent), js engine: hermes
 ERROR  Error: Cannot access realm that has been closed.
```

Comment: Can you include the code your using that generates the error? Also indicate what line throughs the error. Please review [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @jay I tried to add more details, but making a minimal example is not that easy...

Comment: Yeah - isolating is always a challenge. It sounds to me like Realm is going out of scope - but I am not a react expert. We often will comment out all of the code except the code that returns the realm, and then add a temporary button that when clicked, calls this `RealmInstance.objects<Article>(Article.schema.name)` and see if it works. If not, you've narrowed the issue. If so, uncomment some more and try again. Keep adding code back in until it crashes.